# 'Refer' vs 'make reference'

Tags: differences

What is the difference between saying "He referred to something" and "He made reference to something"?

Is it a question of mood? Emphasis? Agency? Different paths to English since the latter is a common French construction?

I want to say "make reference" but I am wondering if I am just being needlessly wordy.

Comment: I would agree that "make reference" is wordier, so I'd prefer "referred to."  These days "reference" as a verb is also increasingly common, as in "he referenced something."  This is even more concise, which is probably why it's catching on, but as something of a traditionalist, I find it jarring and offputting.

Answer (score 3):

The verb `refer` has [several meanings](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/refer). One of the meanings is synonymous with the phrase `make reference to`. The phrase is commonly used so the reader isn't confused (as they would possibly be if `refer` is used).

Consider:

1. Tom referred to a book
2. Tom made reference to a book

The second sentence unambiguously implies Tom alluded to the book, while the first could also mean Tom consulted the book.

Saying 'make reference' is perfectly normal (and [increasingly popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=made%20reference%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmade%20reference%20to%3B%2Cc0), I might add). In my opinion you shouldn't be worried about sounding "needlessly wordy".

Comment: Thanks, you make a good point. And I didn't know about that google function, so thank you very much for that. But I still feel like even within the "synonymous" meanings there is some nuance there that I don't quite grasp. Does anyone feel like these are slightly different things?

Comment: @Tushar, You are kidding right. **An increase from 0.0000050% to 0.0000300%** is not what I would call "increasingly popular".

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences, the two phrases are synonymous.  [The Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/make-reference-to) seems to agree.